# Standard naming for a credential systems

Tags: database-design, logins, naming-convention

Is there a standard naming convention in regards to credential oriented systems? (Logins) The only one I could really come up with (in a shorthand form) is using the word "Gateway". Representing a gateway to further functionality behind a log in form.

Please note. I am **NOT** asking for **suggestions** on what I should name my schema objects. I am asking if there is an established standard for naming such things. If there is not then an adequate answer would outline this fact. Please do not post opinions on what you *believe* is the right way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the mechanism you are describing is an **authentication system**.

Basically speaking, this kind of mechanism allows the identification of a certain party (e.g., a person or a machine process) that is attempting to access a particular system. Said party provides a certain set of credentials that are compared with information stored (or retrieved) by the authentication mechanism, and if such set of credentials *matches* the information stored (or retrieved) by the authentication tool, the involved party receives successful access to the system, otherwise access is denied.

Examples of authentication instruments are the ones created for web applications by means of:

- [ASP.NET Membership](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx)
- [ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity)

If you are interested in authentication processes carried out by concrete database management systems, you might find of help:

- [The IBM DB2 Authentication Methods For Your Server](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.8.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0005435.html)
- [The Microsoft SQL Server Logins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562.aspx) and [Authentication Modes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144284.aspx)
- [The Oracle Authentication Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/authmeth.htm#BABCGGEB)

Authentication systems are closely related to **authorization** components which, to put it short, take care of determining whether a specific party has permissions to perform a precise action within a given system.

A platform that assists in the development of both authentication and authorization elements pertaining to different types of application programs is:

- [The Java Authentication and Authorization Service (JAAS)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/JAASRefGuide.html)